# Removing characters in a string with R

Tags: r, string

How can I delete rows in a DF that have letters on it when they are supposed to be numbers? A table example might be:

```
DT = data.table(x=c("b","b","b","a","a"),v=rnorm(5), j=c("122","1223","g21bg","43","534"))
DF=data.frame(DT)
```

And I need to get:

```
  x          v     j
 b  0.4220836   122
 b -1.9492471  1223
 a  1.4615694    43
 a -0.2294917   534
```

Could be any character non numeric.
I tried

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(DF$j, letters)
```

But I get:

> Error in check_pattern(pattern, string) :    Lengths of string and
>   pattern not compatible

Comment: A reproducible example would be great. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `grepl`

```
DF[!grepl("[A-Za-z]", DF$j), ]
##  x          v    j
##1 b -1.3157423  122
##2 b -1.3514456 1223
##4 a  0.7508370   43
##5 a  0.3476453  534
```

But, really, you have a `data.table` object, why are you converting it to a `data.frame`?? That doesn't make any sense to me. You can do the same within your original `data.table`

```
DT[!grepl("[A-Za-z]", j), ]
#    x           v    j
# 1: b  0.03008628  122
# 2: b -0.72063192 1223
# 3: a  0.94851720   43
# 4: a -0.72384496  534
```

Or using `grep` combined with `invert = TRUE`

```
DT[grep("[A-Za-z]", j, invert = TRUE), ]
```

Or if you want to use `str_detect` (like in your post)

```
library(stringr)
DT[!str_detect(j, "[A-Za-z]"), ]
```

Although `str_detect` is just a wrapper for `grepl`